# An algorithm for the set of subsets with equal sums of a set of numbers (distinct partitions)

Tags: algorithms, recursion, integer-partitions

Given a set $T\subset\mathbb N^+$ called the set of terms and let $T_n=\{k\in T|k\leq n\}$.
I want to design an efficient algorithm computing the set $\mathcal S_n$ of all subsets $S\subseteq T$ such that
$n=\sum_{m\in S} m$, for $n\in \mathbb N$. With efficient I mean significantly faster than calculating the set of all subsets of $T_n$ and check the sums.

There seems to be a rule of recursion 
$$\mathcal S_n=\bigcup_{t\in T}\mathcal f(S_{n-t},t)$$
for $n\neq 2t$ (for some $t\in T$), where 
$f(X,x)=\{A|\exists B\in X:A=B\cup \{x\}\}$. But I can't grasp the terminal cases for a recursive algorithm. "Natural" terminal cases, in my opinion, are $n\in T$ such that $|\mathcal S_n|=1$, but those terms are unknown initially.

Is there a reasonable solution to this problem?

Comment: Looking at this quickly, dynamic programming comes to mind. You might look that up and see if it applies.

Comment: @martycohen: Thanks! Dynamic programming and memoization make sense.

Answer (score 1):

No. You can *count* such subsets reasonably efficiently using dynamic programming, but the number of such subsets can be exponential in the size of $T$. Consider, for example, $T = \{1, 2, \ldots, 2u\}$. It contains $u$ pairs of sum $u+1$, so if we have $n = (u+1)\lfloor \frac u 2 \rfloor$ then that gives a lower bound of $\binom{u}{\lfloor u / 2 \rfloor}$ subsets.